# `ubuntu--vg-swap_1 is not ready or not present` whenever I boot, what it means?

Tags: boot, swap

Every day since I installed Ubuntu 13.04 I get an error when I boot.

It's like this:

```
The write station for /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1 is not ready or not present
```

(I'm dutch so it can be different with english). After 10 seconds the mouse will show up, and I'm able to login. It happens every time, but Ubuntu uses the swap, when I start some vm's.

Comment: Can you please provide these outputs? `cat /etc/fstab` and `sudo blkid`

Answer (score 0):

I have just started with Ubuntu so perhaps someone more knowledgeable can shed some more light on the issue; however, I was getting the same error message and in my case at least, it seemed to be related to the encryption of the swap partition.

It seems that when you choose the "encrypt home directory" option during the install, this also encrypts your swap partition. I am guessing that because your swap partition is encrypted it is not seen during the boot sequence and the "... --vg-swap_1 is not ready or not present" message appears.

I re-installed and chose not to "encrypt the home directory" which seems to prevent the "... --vg-swap_1 is not ready or not present" message from showing. So this solution to preventing the error message should be balanced against the lack of encryption.

Good luck!